# How do I set up a has_many association where one model has two sets of jsonb ids in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, has-many, jsonb

I want to be able to query a user's games where their user_id is in the games' move's white_user_ids or black_user_ids. I also want to be able to query a game's users where its move's white_user_ids or black_user_ids correspond to users.

EDIT:

Before I start explaining my question in more detail, I came up with a workaround:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def games
    Game.where( [ "moves -> 'black_user_ids' @> '?' OR moves -> 'white_user_ids' @> '?'", self.id, self.id ] )
  end
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :moves, HashSerializer
  store_accessor :moves, :white_user_ids, :black_user_ids

  def users
    User.find((self.white_user_ids + self.black_user_ids).uniq)
  end
end
```

Is there anything wrong with creating custom methods with the names I want, instead of writing out `has_many ...`? If that is a hack and bad, then please keep reading and feel free to answer.

Initial question:

Here is the most basic version of the schema for this question:

```
User
  id

Game
  id
  moves - jsonb
    white_user_ids - integer array
    black_user_ids - integer array
```

I have created an expression index for both user_ids:

```
execute <<-SQL
  CREATE INDEX moves_white_user_ids_on_games ON games USING GIN ((moves->'white_user_ids'));
  CREATE INDEX moves_black_user_ids_on_games ON games USING GIN ((moves->'black_user_ids'));
SQL
```

I don't know how to set up the relationship between users and games. There is clearly some kind of has_many relationship, or maybe even a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship. But I am storing all the data that I would need to make the association in the games table, moves jsonb column.

Examples:

```
<User id: 1>
<User id: 5>
<User id: 6>
<User id: 11>
<User id: 17>
<User id: 20>
<User id: 23>
<User id: 35>
<User id: 76>
<User id: 89>
<User id: 93>

<Game id: 1, moves: {"black_user_ids"=>[88],
                     "white_user_ids"=>[23]}>
<Game id: 2, moves: {"black_user_ids"=>[6, 1, 11, 76, 17, 23],
                     "white_user_ids"=>[93, 89, 1, 35, 20, 5, 6]}>
<Game id: 3, moves: {"black_user_ids"=>[76, 68, 20, 96, 19, 3],
                     "white_user_ids"=>[82, 48, 29, 37, 20, 74]}>
<Game id: 4, moves: {"black_user_ids"=>[82],
                     "white_user_ids"=>[74, 16]}>
<Game id: 5, moves: {"black_user_ids"=>[22, 41, 25, 78, 50],
                     "white_user_ids"=>[24, 10, 99, 26, 1, 4]}>
```

User associations/scopes:

`User.find(1).games` would return games [2, 5], any unique game where either black_user_ids or white_user_ids has their user_id.

`User.find(1).black_games` would return game [2], any game where black_user_ids has their user_id.

`User.find(1).white_games` would return games [2, 5], any game where white_user_ids has their user_id.

Game associations/scopes:

`Game.find(2).users` would return users [1, 5, 6, 11, 17, 20, 23, 35, 76, 89, 93], any unique user in its black_user_ids or white_user_ids.

`Game.find(3).black_users` would return users [3, 19, 20, 68, 76, 96], any user in its black_user_ids.

`Game.find(4).white_users` would return users [16, 74], any user in its white_user_ids.

Comment: http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/5/6/creating-multiple-associations-with-the-same-table/ hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with polymorphic associations.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

The moves table would then have id and type black or white. You can then associate that to game and query black moves or white moves.